# Python Elasticsearch: BulkIndexError: 'not_x_content_exception' while trying to use helpers.bulk

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

So I've been trying to learn Elasticsearch but I've been having a lot of problems. I'm trying to upload the first 150 rows of the csv file into Elasticsearch and while I can create the index, I'm not able to actually insert the csv file. I'm using Elasticsearch 7.11 and Kibana 7.11 along with Python 3.9 This is my code:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
file = "information.csv"
read_csv = panda.read_csv(file)
beginning_of_file = read_csv.head(150)

elasticsearch.indices.delete(index='info_data', ignore=[400, 404])
elasticsearch.indices.create(index='info_data', ignore=400)
helpers.bulk(es, beginning_of_file, index='info_data')
```

I then get the following error:

```
elasticsearch.helpers.errors.BulkIndexError:
('18 document(s) failed to index.', [{'index': {'_index': 'movie_data', '_type': '_doc', '_id': 
'KmwJwncBEtJeL_lPLqQ8', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 
'failed to parse', 'caused_by': {'type': 'not_x_content_exception', 'reason': 'Compressor detection
can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes'
```

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the proper format which ES accepts to index the data, you are reading the content from `csv` file and without converting it to proper format which ES accepts send it.

Please refer [this article](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-python-helpers-to-bulk-load-data-into-an-elasticsearch-index) to get idea on how to transform data to ES compatible format.

Comment: So do csv files need to be converted to JSON before they can be inserted into Elasticsearch?